# How to design the following resolver for GraphQL server?

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server

I am using react-apollo on meteor with mysql and sequelize, I am still a beginner in JS.
Lets assume I have the following resolver function on my apollo-server:

```
 export default resolvers = {
     Query: {
         posts(_, args){
             return Post.findAndCountAll({ where: args   });
         },
         numberOfPosts(){
             return /// the number of selected posts
         }
     }
```

I would like to select some data from the database where some conditions are met and then count the amount of selected rows and return them in the field "numberOfPosts".
`findAndCountAll()` returns an object, which contains the selected rows and the count. I would like to get my `post()` to return only the selected rows, and my numberOfPosts() to return only the count of the selected posts. Right now, both is returned by posts().

**My schema is:**

```
 type Post {
  id: Int
  date: Float
  text: String
}

 type NumberOfPosts{
  total: Int
  filtered: Int
}

type Query {
  posts(
   id: Ind,
   offset: Int,
   limit: Int,
   filter: String): [Post]
  numberOfPosts:[NumberOfPosts] 
}

schema {
  query: Query
}
```

**The Goal is to receive data in the following format:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "numberOfPosts": [
      {
        "total": 1000,
        "filtered": 21
      }
    ],
    "posts": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "date": 5105626122,
        "text": "jzybiwutudi"
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

**My work so far:
Try 1:**

```
  let selectedCount;
export default resolvers = {
    Query: {
        posts(_, args){
            return Post.findAndCountAll({where: args}).then(
                function (results) {
                    selectedCount = results.count;
                    return results.rows
                });
        },
        numberOfPosts(){
            return selectedCount
        }
    }}
```

So I am defining a helping variable outside of resolvers, and set it to the number of selected rows, then the count is returned in `numberOfPosts()`, which works, but the problem with this is, `return results.rows` causes an error, and I do not understand why.

another issue is, that `selectedCount` is always the previous number of rows

**Try 2**

Another solution that seems to work is to Pass the arguments twice into the GraphQL query, like so:

```
{
  numberOfPosts(filter: "example") {
    total
    filtered
  }
  posts(filter: "example") {
    id
    date
    text
  }
}
```

Then both resolver functions know the same arguments, so I can select and count the same posts. But this looks not right to me, since I have to pass the same args twice, they will also be transmitted twice...

Comment: i don't know anything about `react-apollo`, but I would highly recommend NOT creating a `selectedCount` variable where one query would assign the result for another query

Comment: thank you, do you have any tips how to pass the result to the other query?

Comment: i'm taking it that these are two independent queries and not two related fields on one query?

Comment: it seems like these resolver methods correspond directly with your schema. can you update your question and post an example of what that looks like? If your `rootValue` has a field name `numberOfPosts` being returned already, then you don't need to add this resolver. Would it make more sense to design the db to always have a field that contains that value instead?

Comment: Maybe, but I don't know how to do that yet. I have edited my Question, please take a look at it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should think more about the design and what each of those queries should do. Those queries should not mutate the database or the global state.

The best thing you can do is to simply define a new type that includes `total` and `filtered`, like what you did as `NumberOfPosts` in your first try, and also the list of posts.

So, your schema would be like:

```
type Post {
  id: Int
  date: Float
  text: String
}

type PostList {
  total: Int
  filtered: Int
  posts: [Post]
}

type Query {
  posts(
    id: Ind,
    offset: Int,
    limit: Int,
    filter: String): PostList
}

schema {
  query: Query
}
```

And you resolve `posts` like:

```
posts(_, args) {
  return Post.findAndCountAll({ where: args }).then(result => {
    return {
      total: 1000,
      filtered: result.count,
      posts: result.rows
    }
  })
}
```

Notice how I just put 1000 for the total number. You can not get the total number of rows with `findAndCountAll`. If you that, need you can run two different queries in parallel and use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for them to be resolved.

```
posts(_, args) {
  return Promise.all([
    Post.count(),
    Post.findAndCountAll({ where: args })
  ]).then(data => {
    return {
      total: data[0],
      filtered: data[1].count,
      posts: data[1].rows
    }
  })
}
```

The above code also could benefit from [ES6's destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
posts(_, args) {
  return Promise.all([
    Post.count(),
    Post.findAndCountAll({ where: args })
  ]).then(([totalCount, filteredData]) => {
    return {
      total: totalCount,
      filtered: filteredData.count,
      posts: filteredData.rows
    }
  })
}
```

Now you can run:

```
query {
  posts(filter:"example") {
    total
    filtered
    posts {
      id
      date
      text
    }
  }
}
```

and get:

```
{
  "data": {
    "posts": {
      "total": 1000,
      "filtered": 21,
      "posts": [
        {
          "id": 4,
          "date": 5105626122,
          "text": "jzybiwutudi"
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very good answer. I would like to add that Post.findAndCountAll already returns the count of rows, so instead of filteredData.rows.length one could simply use filteredData.count.

Comment: Oh I meant to do that as well. Updated answer for future references :) I'm  glad it helped.

Comment: Btw. ist this the same as your solution with promise all?: posts(_, args) {
    return Post.findAndCountAll({ where: args }).then(data => {
        return {
            total: Post.count(),
            filtered: data[1].count,
            posts: data[1].rows
        }
    })
} I mean will the return wait till Post.count() returns the value? Or is it more safe to use a Promise.all? Because it works like this too...

Comment: @henk if you chain those promises, the second one would wait for the first one to be resolved first. As those two are independent, we can parallelize them, and use `Promise.all` to wait for both to be finished. Yours works too I believe, it is just more performant in this case to parallelize them.

Comment: @henk and I believe, in your code, you don't need to use it like `data[1].`. just `data.` should be right.

Comment: `posts(_, args) {` here `posts` should be matched with graphql request param name as like here `query {
  posts(filter:"example") {` right ?

Comment: @AjayS yeah that function is the function that is passed to graphql as a `posts` resolver. The name of the function could be anything as long as it's tied to the `posts` in ` query { posts(filter:"example") }`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Was trying to figure out how to make the resolvers talk to each other for the count... then saw your solution. Turns out I just have to improve my schema. :)