# How to use Promise.all in graphql resolver for neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, apollo-server

I have multiple user nodes (around 45 users) and I want to return the total users count as well as the User's details too in a single query. (Similar to [How to design the following resolver for GraphQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41434241/how-to-design-the-following-resolver-for-graphql-server))

My schema:

```
type User {
    ID: Int
    name: String
}

type Query {
  users: [User]
}
```

And after running the resolver for **users** query, I want to pull the total count as well as the users details too like below:

```
    {
      "data": {
        "users": {
          "total": 45
          "users": [
            {
              "ID": 1,
              "name": "User A"
            },
            {
              "ID": 2,
              "name": "User B"
            },
            ...
          ]
        }
```

But I am confused how to use Promise.all in neo4j. I tried to look how the promise works in neo4j but I did not find any desired info.
So, could you please let me know how should I write my resolver for this case ? Any help would be appreciable !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Promise.all is not different in neo4j. Promise.all is from javascript. To write resolver you can do following:

```
let countQuery = "MATCH(n:User) RETURN count(n) as count;";
let userQuery = "MATCH(u:User) RETURN u;";
return Promise.all([
  dbSession().run(countQuery, params),
  dbSession().run(userQuery, params)
]).then((data) => {
  return {
    total: data[0].records.map(record => {return record.get('count')}
    users: data[1].records.map(record => {return record.get('u')}
  }
})
```

In your schema type you can change it to following:

```
type User {
    ID: Int
    name: String
}
type PagedData {
   total: Int,
   users: [User]
}
type Query {
  users: PagedData
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was expecting :)